# Induction and Recursion. What does $C_n$ mean? and how to measure the length of a construction?

Tags: combinatorics, logic

There is something I don´t understand, can you tell me, in the image, why the "tree" is $C_5$? And what is its length? I have been reading a lot and I don't get it and I have to solve a problem from the Enderton:
"Suppose that $C$ is generated from a set $B= \{a, b\}$ by the binary operation $f$ and unary operation $g$. List all the members of $C_2$. How many members might $C_3$ have? $C_4$?"

Help me with your light please!
Thanks a lot in advance

Taken from Enderton's Mathematical introduction to Logic.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pebcw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $x_1 = b$, $x_2 = f(x_1, x_1)$, $x_3 = a$, $x_4 = f(x_3, x_2)$, $x_5 = g(x_4)$. It reflects the computation described by the tree and shows that the term $g(f(a,f(b,b)))$ is in $C_5$.

For the terms in $C_2$, your sequence starts by $x_1 = a$ or $x_1 = b$ and $x_2$ is one of $x_2 = f(x_1, x_1)$ or $x_2 = g(x_1)$. This gives you the term $f(a,a)$, $f(b,b)$, $g(a)$ and $g(b)$.

**Hint**. For the terms in $C_3$, you have the same first step, but you have two other possible second steps: $x_2 = a$ and $x_2 = b$. The possible third steps are $x_3 = f(x_1, x_1)$, $x_3 = f(x_1, x_2)$, $x_3 = f(x_2, x_1)$, $x_3 = f(x_2, x_2)$, $x_3 = g(x_1)$ and $x_3 = g(x_2)$.

Comment: I think I got it, the n is defined by the number of operations or “bricks” by whom the construction is generated, and these bricks are not deterministic, I mean, there are more posible bricks according to the operations we are allowed to make, I could build another Cn construction different than the this one by using the same operations right? And what about the lenght? is it literally the number of signs and symbols we are using? I deeply appreciate your answers. Love from Mexico.

Comment: Indeed, the *length* is the number of terms of the sequence $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$, that is $n$. You also are right to say that you can have several $C_n$ constructions for a given term. For instance, on your example, you could take $x_1 = a$, $x_2 = b$, $x_3 = f(x_2, x_2)$, $x_4 = f(x_1, x_3)$, $x_5 = g(x_4)$.